# Index 1 out of range [0..1) image

Tags: android, json, kotlin, picasso, okhttp

i'm trying to get image from json and load it into xml. and i already get the image url and just have to load it. but whenever i try to load the image it always shows `Index 1 out of range [0..1)` error messege but i dont know why it happen.

this is my code

```
val url = "https://www.thesportsdb.com/api/v1/json/1/lookupteam.php?id=133616"
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
    val client = OkHttpClient()
    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback, okhttp3.Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            println("failed")
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: okhttp3.Call?, response: okhttp3.Response?) {
            val body = response?.body()?.string()
            println(body)
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(body)
            val jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("teams")
            for (i in 0..jsonArray.length()) {
                val jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val lambang = jsonObject2.getString("strTeamBadge")
                Log.v("lambang", "" + lambang)
                Picasso.get().load(lambang).into(badge_away)
            }
        }
    })
```

and when i change the for to `while(i<jsonArray.length()` it load the image over and over without stop.
please if you know how to solve this please help

ps: my jsonArray actually only have 1 index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `0..jsonArray.length()` 
with `0..jsonArray.length()-1` or `0 until jsonArray.length()`  
array indexes are zero based so the last element has index equal to `jsonArray.length()-1`.  
When you use `0 until jsonArray.length()` the last value `jsonArray.length()` is excluded.  
If the array has only 1 element then the for loop should execute just once. 
**Edit**: this is a very useful link for this case [Kotlin Ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html)

Comment: thank you so much it works. I think `..` and `until` are the same